# XSD having metadata at each field level

Tags: xsd, metadata

i have XML structure as below (just part of large XML)

```
<Person>
<firstName>
<lastName>
<Partner>
   <firstName>
...
</Person>
```

i need to keep additional metadata with each field for example to indicate if its updatable or not

i c two approaches

1) add the metadata at each FIELD level. i feel this overly complicates the XSD as each element is now an OBJECT

```
<Person>
   <firstName updatable="true" ... />
   ...
</Person>
```

2) separate out the metadata as below

BUt how do i link the metadata to the data? via a uniquie name? can someone consuming the XML easily link it? 
Is there a better way? Thanks!

```
 <data>
     <Person>one
       <firstName>
       <lastName>
       <Partner>
           <firstName>
       ...
     </Person>
     <Person>two
       <firstName>
       <lastName>
       <Partner>
           <firstName>
       ...
    </Person>
</data>
<metadata>
    <field name="firstName" updateble="false"/>
    ....
</metadata>
```

i think this is similar to 
[Add metadata to an XSD definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633969/add-metadata-to-an-xsd-definition)
but it does not have any answer

Comment: also it wont be just one metadata property ("updatable") but it can be many like <key,value> pairs.

Comment: Is this metadata static in relationship to the model describing your XML, or is it specific to an instance of your XML? Please clarify and I'll give you my opinion...

Comment: static in relationship to model Petru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My (maybe rhetoric) question would be why would someone want to see this metadata with each XML if it is static in relationship to the model?

I'll show you a UBL XSD snippet (XML namespaces elided as irrelevant):

```
 <xsd:element ref="cbc:UBLVersionID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xsd:annotation>
       <xsd:documentation>
          <ccts:Component>
             <ccts:ComponentType>BBIE</ccts:ComponentType>
             <ccts:DictionaryEntryName>Application Response. UBL Version Identifier. Identifier</ccts:DictionaryEntryName>
             <ccts:Definition>The earliest version of the UBL 2 schema for this document type that defines all of the elements that might be encountered in the current instance.</ccts:Definition>
             <ccts:Cardinality>0..1</ccts:Cardinality>
             <ccts:ObjectClass>Application Response</ccts:ObjectClass>
             <ccts:PropertyTerm>UBL Version Identifier</ccts:PropertyTerm>
             <ccts:RepresentationTerm>Identifier</ccts:RepresentationTerm>
             <ccts:DataType>Identifier. Type</ccts:DataType>
             <ccts:Examples>2.0.5</ccts:Examples>
          </ccts:Component>
       </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
 </xsd:element>
```

You could see here that there's a lot of structured data which could easily pass as something related to your question. Fundamentally though, this is a mechanism that uses the XSD annotations mechanism, to achieve things in relationship to the XSD. Another one is that used by JAXB custom binding mechanism:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="ZipCodeType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <jxb:javaType name="int" parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseInt" printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printInt"/>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="10000"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

While this is different than the UBL example, (documentation vs. appinfo), both are using the XSD annotation mechanism.

JAXB's custom bindings also supports a model where the custom bindings are separate from the XSD (in their own separate XML file). The correlation between the custom binding file (the metadata in your case) and the XSD (the XML in your case) is done through XPath matches.

This brings about another clarification: what is the processing model you have in mind? Dynamic (i.e. the metamodel is static, but can be applied to arbitrary XSDs)? Platform? Below is a solution that could work for what you need, in a dynamic fashion, if it happens to match your platform.

.NET:

- Build an XSD the way I've referred to above (i.e. annotations of some sort).
- At runtime, validate your XML against this XSD. Each node will then have the [SchemaInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.xml.xmlnode.schemainfo.aspx) property filled in. Using classes in  [System.Xml.Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.aspx) you could easily process the [SchemaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.xml.schema.ixmlschemainfo.schemaelement.aspx) or [SchemaAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.xml.schema.ixmlschemainfo.schemaattribute.aspx) in your SchemaInfo property as an [XmlSchemaAnnotated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaannotated.aspx) class, which is what both are.

The above is basically PSVI applied to your XML. The same exists for Java (on this [Xerces page](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html) search for `How do I retrieve PSVI from the DOM?`)...

I could picture solutions for XSLT as well, or not involving XSD at all... the above though should be sufficient to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Petru. but i think i misunderstood you "static vs dynamic" question n missled you, sorry.<br>. The metadata comes from the database i.e. its dynamic. BUT its the SAME for a given TYPE <BR> what i mean is that there can be several <PERSON> instances but they will all have the SAME metadata. <Br> I have decided for now to go via the FIELD approach keeping the data n metadata together.